# How to Use a Function inside WndProc that exists in another file

Tags: c++, winapi

So, I am not finding an answer to this anywhere.  Suppose that, for the sake or my sanity, I want to handle the code for interaction with a button creating with the Win32 API in a seperate file.

Currently I have the following in my WinMain file:

```
  LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (message)
    {
    /*
    Added
    */
    //creating a windows in order to display a button
    case WM_CREATE:
        {
            button = CreateWindowA("button", "Identify Devices on Current Network",
                            WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | BS_DEFPUSHBUTTON, 
                            10, 10, 300, 25, 
                            hWnd, (HMENU) ID_BTNIDCN, GetModuleHandle(NULL), NULL);
        }
        break;
    /*
    Added
    */
    case WM_COMMAND:
        {
            int wmId = LOWORD(wParam);
            // Parse the menu selections:
            switch (wmId)
            {
            /*
            Added
            */

            case ID_BTNIDCN:
                {
                    queryDevices(hWnd); //this is in another file
                    //Any action to take when button is presed
                    //In this case, creating a message box to display testing, with title test.
                    //MessageBoxA(hWnd, "Test", "Testing", MB_OK);
                }
                break;
```

And I have this in my Query Devices File:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "commonheader.h"
#include "targetver.h"
#include "resource.h"

using namespace std;

//Handing the Button Press
void queryDevices(HWND hWnd)
{
    MessageBoxA(hWnd, "Test", "Testing", MB_OK);
};
```

I also have a common .h file that contains the relevant code:

```
#pragma once

#include "resource.h"

//Custom Files to be included
#include "customfile.cpp"

//Custom Functions
//IdentifyDevicesonCurrentNetwork.cpp
void queryDevices(HWND hWnd);
```

The idea here is to have the code that is executed when you push the button contained in another file so that it is relatively easily to edit and modify without screwing up the WinMain file in some way.

Any suggestions?  Visual Stupid is complaining that my function already has a body.

Comment: -> `#include "customfile.cpp"` <-  Visual Smart tells you that `queryDevices` has a body in both `WinMain` and `customfile.cpp` translation units since you've included file containing function body into common header.

Comment: [mcve] required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When your compiler translates your source files (`.cpp`), it generates code for your function body. If you now include this file again in a header file, the same code for the function body is generated again when the header file is translated. 
This essentially leads to having two identical functions and the linker does not know what to with them.

To fix this, simply remove the `#include "customfile.cpp"` from your header files. In general, never include any source files (`.cpp`) in any header files.